# CakePHP Subcake Redirect

Tags: cakephp, redirect

I have a problem with CakePHP (1.3) project, i need to create projects inside the same domain/hosting of other project, like this:

```
app
cake
plugins
templates
vendors
ADMINONE (Cake project files here)
ADMINTWO (another Cake project files here)
.htaccess
index.php
README
```

The problem is, when I put the CakePHP code inside `ADMINONE` or `ADMINTWO` to create the other cake projects, if I put the url `http://domain.com/ADMINONE/`, the URL redirects to `http://domain.com` or the cake read the `/ADMINONE` as a controller name.

How can I redirect this URL to the directory ignoring the primary directory cake's redirect?

Comment: You might want to take a look at installing the other projects as plugins into your main app. That way you can access it using `/pluginname/controller/action`.

Comment: But the others proyects are not mine, and i cant touch the code.. i need to make separate folders and the URL need to Be like "domain.com/ADMINONE/xxxxxx"

Comment: I think you need to rename the app directory.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to change your index.php inside the webroot folder. In there you can set up the 
APP_DIR and the ROOT if need be.